# What is the benefit of using filter_has_var() over isset()

Tags: php

I'm a little confused with the benefit of using `filter_has_var($_POST['id'])` over `isset($_POST['id'])`.

Can Somebody please tell me if it's simply an alias function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not alot ;)  According to the manual page for [filter_has_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-has-var.php) one user finds `filter_has_var` a little quicker.  Also worth noting... `filter_has_var` isn't working on the live array (`$_POST`) but on the actual provided input... if you ever add/remove/update what's in that array you won't see those changes with a `filter_has_var` call (while `isset` will reflect the current state)

By the way the usage is `filter_has_var(INPUT_POST,"id");`

Update: Perhaps worth mentioning, `filter_has_var` was introduced in PHP 5.2.0 (somewhat new) while `isset` has been around for all of PHP4+5.  Most servers keep up to date on this, but `isset` will always work (no one still runs PHP3 do they?)

Comment: Indeed, plus configuring automatic systems can be somewhat more readable / easier (`$source = INPUT_GET;var_dump(filter_has_var($source,'foobar'));` vs. `$source = '_GET';var_dump(isset($$source[foobar']));`

Comment: oh yeah it's filter_has_var(INPUT_POST,"id"); appended the $_POST by mistake, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 7):

First of all, it's not

```
filter_has_var($_POST['id'])
```

It's

```
filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'id')
```

Secondly, it doesn't actually query the `$_POST` superglobal. It analyzes the request parameter that came in with the request, so it's a better method to use in case `$_POST` gets dirtied in some way by the PHP script.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock for the answer, I chose filter_has_var() then

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean `filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'id')` over `isset($_POST['id'])`.

There is a small difference in that `isset` returns false if `$_POST['id']` is `NULL`; you'd have to use `key_exists('id', $_POST)` to have similar behavior in that regard.

Besides that, the only difference is that `filter_has_var` doesn't consider modifications to the `$_POST` array (see [this comment](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-has-var.php#88228)).

Comment: Hmm, but can `$_POST['id']` reasonably ever be `NULL`? The input data is always a string.

Comment: @mario Right. I don't think so, unless `$_POST` was written to.

Comment: @mario: No, it can never be in this context. As `filter_has_var` deals with the raw input, it deals only and exclusively with strings, so `null` may never occur.

Comment: @nikic Well, not only strings, they can also be arrays. But yes, ` $_POST['id']` can be null only via an assignment after the script starts to run.

Answer (score 1):

Function doesn't check live array

```
<?php
$_GET['a'] = 1;
echo filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'a') ? 'Exist' : 'Not exist';
```

will print Not exist

Comment: Unless, of course, the URL is something like `test.php?a=1` ;)