# Edit/Update button in PHP

Tags: php

Im new to PHP and I am looking for a way on how to put distinctions to buttons created using a looping statement. My task is like this: Every data in a table will be displayed and a corresponding update button for each data will follow through looping. If the update button is clicked, the data will be updated.

This is my code:

```
<?php
        $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM POSTS where `post_status`= 1 order by `post_date` DESC");

        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {

            $ID=$data['post_id'];

            echo"<tr>";
                echo"<td>".$ID ."</td>";
            echo"</tr>";


            echo"<tr>";
                echo"<td>"."on ".$data['post_date'] ."</td>";
            echo"</tr>";

            echo"<tr>";
                echo"<td>".$data['post_title']."</td>";
            echo"</tr>";

            echo"<tr>";
                echo"<td>" .htmlspecialchars_decode($data['post_body'])."<br/>"."</td>";
            echo"</tr>";

            echo"<tr>";
                echo"<td rowspan=1>"."<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Approve\" name=\"$ID\">"."</td>";
            echo"</tr>";

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td colspan=4>"."<hr/>"."</td>";
            echo"</tr>";


            if(isset($_POST['Approve']))
            {

                $a=$ID;
                $query2 = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE POSTS SET post_status = '2' WHERE post_id='$a'");
            }

        }


        ?>
```

Sorry for my bad programming skill. Hope you can help me guys. Thanks!

Comment: remove your `if` statement from while loop

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to do the var validation out of the loop.

Oh, and use filter_has_var instead of isset and only let php do the php stuff if possible.

Why should you use filter_* instead of isset()? because of [What is the benefit of using filter_has_var() over isset()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899420/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-filter-has-var-over-isset)

```
   <?php
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM POSTS where `post_status`= 1 order by `post_date` DESC");

    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {

        $ID=$data['post_id'];

        ?>
           <tr><td><?php echo $ID; ?></td></tr>
           <tr><td>on <?php echo $data['post_date']; ?></td></tr>
           <tr><td><?php echo $data['post_title']; ?></td></tr>
           <tr><td><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($data['post_body']); ?><br/></td>
            </tr>
<?php // and so on.. 

        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td rowspan=1>"."<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Approve\" name=\"$ID\">"."</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
?>
        <tr><td colspan=4>.<hr/>.</td></tr>
<?php


    }
    if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST,'Approve'))   {
            $a=$ID;
            $query2 = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE POSTS SET post_status = '2' WHERE post_id='$a'");
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST,'Approve'))   { // you missed the closing quote and placed a closing bracket instead

Comment: ? hu? dont get it. Whats wrong with filter_has_var?

Comment: you fixed it now :) 
you had it like this initially: if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST,'Approve])) {

Comment: you are fast ;-) modified this within 5 seconds after post :P

Comment: just wanted to make sure @SmashedPotato did not use it that way :)

Answer (score 1):

U can use the `button` html for this :

```
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    ....
    echo '<button type="submit" name="btn_update" value="'. $ID. '">Update</button>';

}
```

This way the id of the row thats need to be updated will be in `$_POST['btn_update']`;
Dont forget to validate the posted ID though

Answer (score 1):

if i was you i'll do this using the get method like this :

```
        <?php
            $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM POSTS where `post_status`= 1 order by `post_date` DESC");

            while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            {

                $ID=$data['post_id'];

                echo"<tr>";
                    echo"<td>".$ID ."</td>";
                echo"</tr>";


                echo"<tr>";
                    echo"<td>"."on ".$data['post_date'] ."</td>";
                echo"</tr>";

                echo"<tr>";
                    echo"<td>".$data['post_title']."</td>";
                echo"</tr>";

                echo"<tr>";
                    echo"<td>" .htmlspecialchars_decode($data['post_body'])."<br/>"."</td>";
                echo"</tr>";

                echo"<tr>";
                    echo"<td rowspan=1>"."<a href=\"your current page url?action=update&id=".$ID."\">Approve</a>"."</td>";
                echo"</tr>";

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td colspan=4>"."<hr/>"."</td>";
                echo"</tr>";
    }
?>
```

then in the top of your page you put this code :

```
<?php
        if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']==update){
    if(isset$_GET['id']){
    $a=$_GET['id'];
                    $query2 = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE POSTS SET post_status = '2' WHERE post_id='$a'");
                }
    }
    ?>
```